Force GeoJSON files to store polygons' vertices counter clockwise with PyQGIS
GeoJSON is supposed to store polygons' outer boundaries counter clockwise and the inner rings clockwise. I do not have a preference for one or the other but QGIS is not storing the data uniformly in GeoJSON files, some of them in one of the orientation, and some others in the other. In fact, often in the same GeoJSON file, some Multipolygons are clockwise and others are stored counter clockwise.
QgsGeometry.forcePolygonCounterClockwise()

The above doesn't work.
I've tried to change all the polygonal geometry with the following code (those are all QgsMultipolygon.)
def forceGeometriesCounterClockwise(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    
layers = instance.parameterAsLayerList(parameters, "INPUT", context)

for layer in layers:
    
    layer.startEditing()
    
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        
        geometry = feature.geometry()
        
        if (geometry.isPolygonClockwise()):
            
            for part in geometry.parts():
                
                part.setExteriorRing(part.exteriorRing().reversed())
                
                for i in range(part.numInteriorRings()):
                    part.setInteriorRing(i, part.interiorRing(i).reversed())
        
        layer.changeGeometry(feature.id(), geometry)
    
    layer.commitChanges()
    
return {"OUTPUT": layers}

The problem is that no edit is saved. QGIS always reorder the vertices back in the initial orientation.

Note: the [GJ2008] specification did not discuss linear ring winding  order.  For backwards compatibility, parsers SHOULD NOT reject  Polygons that do not follow the right-hand rule.  ...  Wondering whether using the RFC7946=YES option when creating your GeoJSON will fix the issue for you.  no idea how to do this in PyQGIS though

@nmtoken, using RFC7946=YES did the trick indeed. It turned all the data counter clockwise. Now the problem is that the layers' geometry type becomes 'Polygon' from 'Multipolygon', including when using the 'Polygon' and 'Force multi-type' option.

Is layer.commitErrors() empty? https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.commitErrors

The Force multi-type issue with RFC7946=YES is probably a GDAL bug.
